# IE6 (yes, IE6) css spacing issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm building a [page](http://nacremedia.com/other/index.htm) which works fine in all browsers except IE6, where a small space appears below the cart. The background also has a gap in IE6, so I'm wondering what might be causing that, as it's probably related to the main issue.

If anyone could help I would *really* appreciate it! Many thanks.

Comment: You should ask this over at http://doctype.com .

Comment: Thanks, just have. Shouldn't be anything that anyone here can't handle though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi add this in your style file

```
#navigation {
        width:736px;
        height:auto;
        background:url(../images/nav.gif) no-repeat;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Hi tim in #navigation  id use height auto
height:auto;

Comment: Awesome, thanks kc! It causes problems for other browsers, so I've made it so only IE6 has this fix :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a ie6 only stylesheet? Add this to the head tag and then add the appropriate styles to the css document and they should only apply to ie6.

```
 <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6_xxx.css"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: I would only have a use for that if I had a solution for IE6.